# Export options for printing with Aperture 3

Tags: software, image-quality, apple-aperture, photo-editing

I am about to get my pictures published in a magazine. I am going send the pictures to the publisher, thus not printing them myself. Therefore I am curious about how to export the pictures appropriately from Aperture 3. I know how to export from Aperture. Also I have tried to edit the export settings and trying to figure out how these should be set. I noticed that it is possible to set the DPI when exporting.

What are the appropriate export settings for Aperture 3 when using the pictures for print?

- What should the DPI be set to?
- Which colorspace should be used?
- Which file format? TIFF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to do this once, and I sent the people .TIFF files.

DPI is largely irrelevant for you as you are not printing it.  You're dealing with Pixels, not dots at your stage. (ie. not printing).  You just want to send the file at 100% original size.  However many X and Y pixels that is.

Color space is subjective - I use sRGB, which is better for screen viewing as I understand it.  I think Adobe color space is more for printing, but I could be wrong.  I won't advise you on that personally but you could always ask your magazine contact which they prefer?

By the way -- congratulations on getting your photos printed!! It's a good feeling isn't it :-)

Comment: Aha, I did not realize that DPI does not matter in this case. I have asked about the colorspace, but it is interesting for me to understand things a little bit better, hence the question.

Thanks for your congratulations! :)